# Slick lightbox use image title as caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using slick lightbox for lightbox. I am using this library http://mreq.github.io/slick-lightbox/demo/

```
<div class="portfolio-slides">
  <div class="single">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" title="abc1"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300/016243" >
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/016243/" title="abc2"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300/db990b">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/db990b" title="abc3"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
$('.portfolio-slides').slickLightbox({
  itemSelector        : 'a',
  navigateByKeyboard  : true,
  caption: 'caption'
});
```

How can I use image title as caption in slick lightbox?

Comment: just add data-caption="...." attribute to all a tag

Comment: is there any other way? right now not possible to add data caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the `caption` option as provided here - http://mreq.github.io/slick-lightbox/ ?

I am guessing it should be something like the following

```
$('.portfolio-slides').slickLightbox({
  itemSelector        : 'a',
  navigateByKeyboard  : true,
  caption: function(element, info) { return $(element).find('img').attr('title');} 
});
```

Comment: if there is no image title then undefined appears. I solved this using
return $(element).find('img').attr('title') ? $(element).find('img').attr('title') : '';

Answer (score 1):

Try `caption: true`

If it shows `undefined` as the title, use `caption: 'caption'`, which displays the value of the `data-caption` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the caption like this:

```
<a href="http://placehold.it/300x300" data-caption="caption here"></a>
```

Comment: is there any other way? right now not possible to add data caption

Comment: No there is no other alternative as per I know, as you can only add image title as caption using data-caption only. If you can do with js then you can add attribute data-caption using js or jquery.